# Regex Pattern Match With Data and Date

Tags: java, regex, pattern-matching

I need to filter out the strings which matches with [LCK_ or OPN_] only at the starting of file name, but not to consider any where else.

Example source strings:

```
LCK_card_L02NOR19999_2012-11-07-121600 [Invalid/Filter it]
BLTM_L183ROP3289_2012-11-07-121601 [Valid one]
TEMP_LCK_card_L02NOR19999_2012-11-07-121600 [Valid one]
```

I tried like this:

```
LCK_|OPN_
```

But it's also matching TEMP_LCK_XXXXX.

how do I combine the patterns for my rquriement [ignore LCK_ or OPN_ and extract date]?

My regex pattern for date extraction

```
(19|20)\\d\\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-]\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider this code:

```
String[] strs = new String[] {
    "LCK_card_L02NOR19999_2012-11-07-121600", // Invalid
    "BLTM_L183ROP3289_2012-11-07-121601", // Valid one
    "TEMP_LCK_card_L02NOR19999_2012-11-07-121600" // Valid one
};

String pattern = "^(?!(LCK_|OPN_))(.*)((19|20)[0-9]{2}-(0[1-9]|1[012])-(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])-[0-9]{6}).*";

for (String string : strs) {
    boolean m = string.matches(pattern);
    System.out.println(m ? "Valid" : "Invalid");
}
```

This will match first the start of the string (denoted by `^`), then anything *except* `LCK_` or `OPN_` (denoted by `?!`), then 0 or more arbitrary characters, then your date pattern, then possibly a number of characters.

Comment: not matchin for LCK_2012-11-07-121600
Anyway It should reject if starts with LCK_ 
so I am asking for a pattern which will filter strings which Doesn't start with LCK_ and matches date pattern

Comment: @NitinGurram: Try it again. It works for me in those three example strings.

Answer (score 1):

`^(LCK_|OPN_)` - `^` stands for the start of input.

In order to combine this with the rest of your regex, skip any number of arbitrary characters:

```
^(?:LCK_|OPN_).*(19|20)\\d\\d.....
```

(use `?:` if you do not want to capture `LCK_` and `OPN_` into a group).

Comment: thanks. I updated my question. I am struggling to combine them

Comment: Please check the updated answer. Use `.*` to skip irrelevant input.

Comment: I tried ^(?:LCK_|OPN_).*(19|20)\\d\\d[-](0[1-9]|1[012])[-](0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[-]\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d\\d
 
TEMP_LCK_2012-11-07-121600 [for example] didn't match

Comment: So, this is good, right? You were complaining "But it's also matching TEMP_LCK_XXXXX."

Answer (score 1):

Start of the file, or start of the line?

Try this...

```
"^(LCK_|OPN_).*"
```